# Water features in ArcScene viewer not displaying correctly?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, arcscene

I am using ArcMap 10.4.1 and ArcScene 10.4.1.

My scene consists of dtm, multipatches, polygon features and point features. Together they work quite well, except for the water body (polygon) showing where it should not. You can see the outline of the island in the first picture (but with water where it shouldnt be), and when I zoom in, the island appears. In the third image, you can see how the polygon looks in ArcScene.

[image]

[image]

[image]

It seems like there is some problems with the polygon having a hole inside it, and that something isnt rendering correctly or something. I have tried extruding it on top of the terrain and setting a fixed height, but there seem to be something not quite right.

I've also tried setting rendering hierachy, and interpolating the polygon to match the terrain height, but with no success.

Could there be something with the terrain model that is not working 100%? Is there a best practice when combining these types of geodata into ArcScene Viewer?

Comment: My experience with the issue of rendering is the video card memory, Often opening the project on a different machine will show differences. The software may also be doing something like pyramids, where the closer you zoom in the higher the resolution and more accurate.